# How to put values from a text file into an object array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to create an object array that from a text file. The objects I am placing in the array are people objects with 4 parameters. 1st name, last name, an ID number and a height. The text file has a certain number of lines and each element is separated by an exclamation mark. I am trying to take each of the 4 elements to create an object and then place that object into an object array. Here is my code up until now. Also because I am new to java, there is not a lot that I know so the code needs to be simple.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Participants {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String array[] = new String[35];
        Object participants[] = new Object[35];
        int count = 0;
        int counter = -1;
        try {
            File myFile1 = new File("Participants.txt");
            Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(myFile1);
            while (scan1.hasNext()) {
                counter++;
                array[counter] = scan1.next();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("The file can not be read");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(array[i], "!");
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                People person = new People(st.nextToken(), st.nextToken(), st.nextToken(),
                        st.nextToken());
                participants[i] = person;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code basically looks okay - what is the problem?

Comment: Can you provide some samples from your text file ..

Comment: StringTokenizer if depreciated, use split()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented that your code *basically* looks okay. There are some problems I spotted, and I think you may be running into them. You are probably getting a

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Participants.main(Participants.java:22)
```

because `arrays[i]` is empty in

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(array[i], "!");
```

which is because you allocate 35 entries:

```
String array[] = new String[35];
```

and the file contains less lines than that. At least, that's what I'm getting it with this input file:

```
A!B!C!D
E!F!G!H
I!J!K!L
```

which is to be expected.

If I change the first line of the input file into

```
A!B!C
```

I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(Unknown Source)
    at Text2ObjArray.main(Text2ObjArray.java:28)
```

which is because you only check once for a token, but then proceed to read four:

```
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        Person person = new Person(st.nextToken(), st.nextToken(), st.nextToken(), st.nextToken());
```

I'll update with a solution, if it is needed, but here are two suggestions:

1) use an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an `array[]`:

2) Check what you parse: make sure there are 4 tokens per line, and deal with the exceptional case that they are not 4.

**UPDATE**

*Basically*, there's nothing wrong with your program. You already know *"
How to put values from a text file into an object array in java?"*.
Your program runs just fine if you feed it a file with exactly 35 lines containing at least 3 exclamation marks each. If not, it throws the appropriate exceptions:

- a `NullPointerException` if there are less than 35 lines and
- an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if there are more, and
- a `NoSuchElementException` if there are less than 3 exclamation marks on any of the lines.

(Unless, there is a problem is in the `People` class which is unlikely if it is a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)).

Your code only needed a few minor changes to make it work for files with other content. I've kept it simple:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class Text2ObjArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person[] participants = loadFile(new File(args.length > 0
            ? args[0] : "Participants.txt"));
        for (Person p : participants)
            System.out.println("Participant: " + p);
    }
```

I split off `main` merely as good practice - see ['top-down' and 'bottom-up'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_and_bottom-up_design).

To address the `NullPointerException` and `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` We'll use an `ArrayList` instead of an `array[]` to keep track of the lines we read from the file. The advantage of an `ArrayList` is that it can grow and shrink, which is useful if you don't know for sure if `"Participants.txt"` always contains 35 lines.
Also it saves us from replacing our array with a bigger one when it's full. It's a cheap, handy upgrade from an `array[]`, and all that has changed is writing

- [`array.get(i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) instead of `array[i]`
- [`array.set(i,foo)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) instead of `array[i]=foo` and
- [`array.add(foo)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29) instead of `array[counter++]=foo` and
- `array.size()` instead of `array.length`. It is a dynamic array, so you can insert into any position, remove etc.

  ```
  private static Person[] loadFile(File file) {   
      List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
      try (Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(file)) {
          while (scan1.hasNext())
              lines.add(scan1.next());
      } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("File read error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
  ```

This section is changed only in that it reads *up to* 4 tokens, dealing with the `NoSuchElementException`:

```
        Person participants[] = new Person[lines.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(lines.get(i), "!");
            String[] fields = new String[4];
            for (int k = 0; k < fields.length && st.hasMoreTokens(); k++)
                fields[k] = st.nextToken();
            participants[i++] = new Person(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]);
        }

        return participants;
    }
}
```

To run it successfully you'll need to replace `Person` to `People` or use this `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    private String id;
    private String lName;
    private String fName;
    private String height;

    public Person(String id, String fName, String lName, String height) {
        this.id = id;
        this.fName = fName;
        this.lName = lName;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person[" + id + ": " + lName + ", " + fName + ", " + height + "]";
    }
}
```

I hope that this has been helpful.